# True and False Statements, finding variable types

Tags: python

Im trying to decide whether a string variable is a valid integer or float, ive tried try statements but using ASCII seems to be better. I can't get this to work, probably something with the returns and boolean.

```
def validation(valid):
 var=input("no...")
 state=True
 y=0
 for x in range(len(var)):
      if state==False or y==2:
           valid=False
           return valid
      if var[x] == chr(46) or chr(48) <= var[x] <= chr(57):
           if var[x] == chr(46):
                y+=1
           state=True
      else:
           state=False

valid=True
valid = validation(valid)
print(valid)
```

The ASCII characters 46 and 48-57 are a decimal point and numbers 0-9. If there more than one decimal point (representing by y) than it also returns a false statement.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and powerful approach:

```
def isNum(txt):
    try:
        float(txt)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: That only tests if the value is a float.  The OP's question was about a float or int.

Comment: @fiacre: Note that the OP isn't concerned about distinguishig between valid its and valid floats. Marcin's code will work ok on ints, since a string containing a valid representation of an int is also a valid float. A very long string will convert to `inf`, but that doesn't matter here.

Comment: Exactly as PM 2Ring said, this will work on ints too

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way to do this:

```
try:
    float(x)
 except ValueError as e:
    print e
    print "Not a float"
else:
   try:
       int(x)
   except ValueError as e:
       print e
       print "not an integer"
```

You can combine these into a method pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't very efficient, and it doesn't handle negative numbers, or floats written in scientific notation. Using `try`, as in fiacre's answer is the standard way to do this in Python.

But to answer your question, you don't have a `return` statement after the `for` loop, so if all your tests succeed your function returns the default value of `None`. So you just need to put a `return True` at the end of your function.

---

You can make your code a little more efficient by iterating over the string values and testing the characters directly rather than indexing into the string and using `chr()`. Eg,

```
for c in var:
    if c == '.' or '0' <= c <= '9':
        # etc
```

Alternatively,

```
valid_chars = set('-.0123456789')
for c in var:
    if c in valid_chars:
        # etc
```

FWIW, in your existing code Python has to re-calculate `chr(46)` etc on every loop. Sure, that's a pretty fast operation, but it's still wasteful.

Also, there's no need to have both `state` and `valid` in the function.

Comment: What about strings like 45.23-4. Your code would work too

Comment: @MarcinZdunek: That's covered by the stuff in `# etc`. :) I was just illustrating a better way to do the tests, I wasn't attempting to give all the details. The OP's code already has logic to handle multiple decimal points. And I guess I should mention that to handle signs correctly, there's no point putting them into `valid_chars` since a plus or minus sign is only valid at the start of the string. Of course, while I can see the point of doing the validation this way as a learning exercise, I still believe that i real code it's better to use the technique shown in your & fiacre's answers.